# Optimising multiplication modulo a small prime

Tags: python, math, cryptography

I need to do the following operation *many* times:

1. Take two integers `a, b`
2. Compute `a * b mod p`, where `p = 1000000007` and `a, b` are of the same order of magnitude as `p`

My gut feeling is the naive

```
result = a * b
result %= p
```

is inefficient. Can I optimise multiplication modulo `p` much like exponentiation modulo `p` is optimised with `pow(a, b, p)`?

Comment: Well, one simple optimization would be to combine all that into a single statement... it's about 6% faster in my tests.

Comment: Googling "fast modular multiplication" yields a number of papers, such as [this one](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/freeabs_all.jsp?arnumber=5638011).

Comment: 9 digits might be too small for special algorithms such as [Montgomery reduction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Montgomery_reduction) yield any benefit. Don't optimize prematurely. What is the source for `a,b` (data-structure)? What does your profiler say?

Comment: "I have a feeling... is inefficient."  Based on what?  Have you tried it?  What time constraints are you under?  What's your overall algorithm?

Comment: If p = 1000000007 is fixed, then it seems likely speed could be improved by handcoding a little assembly language.  Of course that would be CPU instruction set dependent, which the python tag dissuades me from elaborating as an answer.

Comment: @hardmath: I would very much be interested in the assembly code!

Comment: Sure, but what processor should I target?  I'd guess Intel or AMD, but a lot of machines have a GPU that can be put to use in parallel mode.

Comment: @Randomblue: is your algorithm parallelizable?  IOW, do you need to perform (a*b)%p for lots of different a and b at once, or is the output of one calculation going to be fed iteratively into the next?  If the former, you're probably going to get the biggest ROI from looking at various Python GPU wrappers.

Comment: @DSM: Nope, the output of one calculation is going to be fed iteratively into the next...

Comment: I don't suppose you know the prime factors of `a` and `b` ahead of time?

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft: Nope.

Comment: What makes you think this is slow? It's not very slow when I try it...

Comment: I'd call that a small prime. A large prime as used in crypto, is typically 500-2000 bits, and not just 30. Assuming a,b<p the temporary value of a*b fits a 64 bit int, and should be relatively fast to compute. I expect the modulo operation to be the most expensive part.

Comment: You can write the hole thing into C, that might give you a bit. Don't expect any feasible mathematical optimizations.

Comment: When you apply it many times, I assume you apply it to different pairs Ai,Bi everytime. Is there an order to these pairs, e.g. can you have (3,10), (3,22),(3,25),(3,999) (5,22) .. etc. How sparse are the numbers also?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To do this calculation in assembly, but have it callable from Python, I'd
try [inline assembly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_assembler) from a
[Python module written in C](http://docs.python.org/extending/extending.html).
Both [GCC](http://ibiblio.org/gferg/ldp/GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO.html) and
[MSVC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ks26t93%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)
compilers feature inline assembly, only with differing syntax.

Note that our modulus `p = 1000000007` just fits into 30-bits.  The result
desired `(a*b)%p` can be computed in Intel 80x86 registers given some weak
restrictions on `a,b` not being much bigger than `p`.

**Restrictions on size of `a,b`**

(1) `a,b` are 32-bit unsigned integers

(2) `a*b` is less than `p << 32`, i.e. `p` times 2^32

In particular if `a,b` are each less than `2*p`, overflow will be avoided.
Given (1), it also suffices that either one of them is less than `p`.

The Intel 80x86 instruction MUL can multiply two 32-bit unsigned integers
and store the 64-bit result in accumulator register pair EDX:EAX.  Some
details and quirks of MUL are discussed in Section 10.2.1 of this helpful
[summary](http://webster.cs.ucr.edu/AoA/Windows/HTML/IntegerArithmetic.html).

The instruction DIV can then divide this 64-bit result by a 32-bit constant
(the modulus `p`), storing the quotient in EAX and the remainder in EDX.
See Section 10.2.2 of the last link.  The result we want is that remainder.

It is this division instruction DIV that entails a risk of overflow, should
the 64-bit product in numerator EDX:EAX give a quotient larger than 32-bits
by failing to satisfy (2) above.

I'm working on a code snippet in C/inline assembly for "proof of concept".
However the maximum benefit in speed will depend on batching up arrays of
data `a,b` to process, amortizing the overhead of function calls, etc. in
Python (if that is the target platform).

Comment: Thanks. @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft.  But I mistakenly threw an extra zero into my value for p.  The version in the Question posted (8 zeros between 1 and 7) only needs 30 bits.  I checked and the version with 9 zeros between 1 and 7 isn't prime (divisible by 23), I'll make the correction when I next post my code snippet.

Answer (score 13):

You mention that *"`a, b` are of the same order of magnitude as p."*  Often in cryptography this means that `a,b` are large numbers near `p`, but strictly less-than `p`.

If this is the case, then you could use the simple identity

[image: a-p \equiv a \pmod{p}]

to turn your calculation into

```
result = ((a-p)*(b-p))%p
```

You've then turned one large multiplication into two large subtractions and a small multiplication.  You'll have to profile to see which is faster.

Comment: If you can keep all your results in the machine-native integers rather than requiring promotion to Python's arbitrary-precision integers (which happens seamlessly when the values are big enough to require them), you can save a lot of time.  This looks like a good way to do that.  (Of course, as the answer says, you should do your own testing to see if it's *actually* faster.)

Comment: Timing it, this takes twice the time.

Comment: As long as a, b and p are all 32bit integers (as in OP), I don't think this is going to help.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't answer the question directly, but I would recommend not doing this in pure Python if you're looking for performance. Some options:

- Make a small library in C that does your computations, and use Python's [`ctypes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html) to talk to it.
- Use [numpy](https://numpy.org/); probably the best option if you want to stay out of having to deal with compiling stuff yourself. Doing operations one at a time won't be faster than Python's own operators, but if you can put multiple ones in a numpy array, computations on them will be much faster than the equivalent in Python.
- Use [cython](https://cython.org/) to declare your variables as C integers; again, same as numpy, you will benefit from this the most if you do it in batches (because then you can also optimize the loop).

Comment: +1 there is a fast algorithm, but implementing it in python is not likely to be any faster than (a*b) % p.

Comment: You've mention numpy and cython, but which functions from these libraries implement (a*b)%p in a single call?

Answer (score 0):

Although this is trivally simple, you could try it and save some time on the `mod p` step by building a list of products based on `1000000007` (the size of the list depends on the size of `a` and `b`). Test for modulo on each of those (starting with the highest). Granted, this only helps if `a & b >= sqrt(p) * 2`.

Comment: Heh, this is probably where I cut-and-pasted the extra zero in my value of p!  See BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft's comment to me & my reply.

Comment: @hardmath you certainly did...I was on my phone at the time, on a bus. It was bumpy. Counting zeros is hard. Apologies!

Answer (score 0):

There may be a clue to the optimization if you clarified what you mean by ***many*** times, for example if you were collecting the results from a high frequency loop, the loop may offer the means to optimize your routine.

Say the unoptimized loop was:

```
p = 1000000007
b = 123456789
a = 0
while a < p:
    result = (a * b) % p
    dosomething(a, b, result)
    a += 1
```

you could optimise out the * and % from the high frequency loop:

```
p = 1000000007
b = 123456789
a = 0
result = (a * b) % p
while a < p:
    dosomething(a, b, result)
    a += 1
    result += b
    if result >= p:
        result -= p
```