# Decreasing while loop working time for gigantic numbers

Tags: python, loops, time

```
i = 1
d = 1
e = 20199
a = 10242248284272

while(True):
  print(i)
  if((i*e)%a == 1):
      d = i
      break
  i = i + 1
```

Numbers are given to represent lengths of them.

I have a piece of Python code which works for really huge numbers and I have to wait for a day maybe two. How can I decrease the time needed for the code to run?

Comment: You need to format your code properly. Its difficult to understand what it does at the moment.

Comment: This should run really fast, since it has syntax (indentation) errors.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to multiply big numbers faster?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37404689/how-to-multiply-big-numbers-faster)

Comment: Maybe it would run faster if you didn't print every integer between `i` and what eventually gets assigned to `d`.

Comment: Pretty sure you could just use a `for` loop here, which should be faster as well.

Comment: Are you saying that this code in particular runs slowly, or are you looking for help speeding up code in general? If it is the latter we cannot help without a more concrete example. If it is the former, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9009139/optimising-multiplication-modulo-a-small-prime)

Comment: @bendl: So 10242248284272 would be considered a small prime?

Comment: this problem is np-hard so to solve it faster than via exaustive search would prove p == np and you could be a millionaire

Comment: @ScottHunter that depends on what you consider small, but if you read the page, some people address the problem in a general enough way that it could help. I didn't vote to close, I only pointed to somewhere that could help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a variety of things you can do to speed this up; whether it will be enough is another matter.

- Avoid printing things you don't have to.
- Avoid multiplication.  Instead of computing `i*e` each iteration, you could have a new variable, say `i_e`, which holds this value.  Each time you increment `i`, you can add `e` to it.
- The *vast* majority of your iterations aren't even close to satisfying `(i*e)%a==1`.  If you used a larger increment for `i`, you could avoid testing most of them.  Of course, you have to be careful not to overshoot.
- Because you are doing modular arithmetic, you don't need to use the full value of `i` in your test (though you will still need to track it, for the output)
- Combining the previous two points, you can avoid computing the modulus: If you know that `a<=x<2*a`, then `x-a==1` is equivalent to `x%a==1`.

None of these may be enough to reduce the complexity of the problem, but might be enough to reduce the constant factor to speed things up enough for your purposes.